# How to make a seekable video with Gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer

I'm trying to make a video seekable with Gstreamer, after multiple researches, I found that matroskamux and the filesink plugin will do it, but it does not work.

This is my pipeline :

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv
```

I create a 5 second video :

```
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:05.989791758
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

When I run the discover app from gstreamer:

```
user@IM00343:~/Desktop$ gst-discoverer-1.0 test.mkv 
Analyzing file:///home/user/Desktop/test.mkv
Done discovering file:///home/user/Desktop/test.mkv

Topology:
  container: Matroska
    video: H.264

Properties:
  Duration: 0:00:00.566333333
  Seekable: yes
  Tags: 
      container format: Matroska
      video codec: H264
      minimum bitrate: 989280
      bitrate: 1045608
      maximum bitrate: 989280
```

The duration is 0:00:00.566333333, this value is this the same regardless of the real video duration! And the video is not seekable.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send an EOS (End of stream) event to the pipeline to allow the elements to properly finish their stream. Without this the muxers won't be able to finish the file properly and write indexes and headers that can only be written once everything is processed. Setting the pipeline to NULL as interrupting does will stop everything immediately and muxers will leave the file unfinished.

In gst-launch the `-e` flag should make it push and wait for EOS before stopping the pipeline. In code, if you want to interrupt a recording you need to send the event yourself and then wait for the EOS to be received on the GstBus.

Some inputs such as files have an end. In these cases the source element will usually send the EOS itself when it finishes reading. This is not the case for sources that read from a stream that is theoretically infinite, such as a camera.